# Como Submeter Formulario De Outra Página

Tags: javascript

Estou aplicando *Javascript* na barra de endereço, para redirecionar URL de vídeo do Youtube para https://youtubegomp3.com/?u=coloque_aqui_url_Youtube efetuar download "MP3".

Ja no Site https://youtubegomp3.com/, é necessário clicar no Botão *"Convert"* para iniciar à *Conversão* logo seguido do *Download*.

Estive analisando *Código Fonte* da página e notei que, para iniciar a *Conversão* URL do Youtube ele passa para `convert.php` em seguida `download.php?id=`.

> Em outras palavras - Ele https://youtubegomp3.com/?u= Transfere a  URL de vídeo do Youtube -> para `convert.php` -> em seguida `download.php?id=` pra baixar o "MP3".

## Dúvida

> Teria como passar todo este processo de forma automatizada para o *script*, sem que precise da interveção humana para clicar no botão de "Convert"?

## Código

```
javascript:window.location.href='https://youtubegomp3.com/?u='+encodeURIComponent(location.href)+'&title'+encodeURIComponent(document.title);
```

Answer (score 2):

Não é permitido executar scripts ou obter acesso aos objetos HTML sob um domínio diferente.

Exemplo, se executar uma ação JavaScript a partir do site www.foo.bar para acessar elementos do site www.bar.foo, não obterá êxito.

O motivo são normas básicas de segurança de navegação na internet.

Uma opção para resolver é fazer uma requisição direta com uma linguagem como o PHP. Para isso, leia o código HTML da página alvo para saber quais os parâmetros e a URL que deve requisitar.

Outro meio recomendado é procurar saber se o website alvo fornece alguma API, portanto, antes de começar a fazer quaisquer gambiarras, procure saber se existe uma API (webservice).

Comment: Ok! Sempre antes de desenvolver e me envolver com Script procuro ir direto no rodapé do WebSite afim de me informar se há algum(a) ferramenta(s) para desenvolvedor/webmaster. Por outro lado, a minha dúvida foi coberta com sua explicação. ATT+